# sbt stage : not a valid command

Tags: scala, heroku, sbt

I am trying to follow the tutorial for scala and spray with this great template : http://typesafe.com/activator/template/activator-akka-spray

Then I follow instruction for Heroku deployment : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-scala

I encounter a problem when running the command "*sbt clean compile stage*" in order to prepare a deployment on Heroku. Here is the error message :

```
[info] Loading project definition from /.../activator-akka-spray/project
[info] Set current project to activator-akka-spray (in build file:/.../activator-akka-spray/)
[error] Not a valid command: stage (similar: last-grep, set, last)
[error] Expected '/'
[error] Expected ':'
[error] Not a valid key: stage (similar: state, target, tags)
[error] stage
[error] ^
```

Has anyone encountered a similar error ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the `StartScriptPlugin` from Typesafe in the `build.sbt`, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-scala#declare-app-dependencies).

Comment: It seems to work locally when added at the top of the root _build.sbt_ file, and not if added to the _/project/build.sbt_ file. But the deployment on Heroku still fails with the same error.

Comment: After a small correction of the _system.properties_ location (at the root), it works. Thanks a lot.