# Why does "sbt stage" fail with Not a valid command?

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager

I am getting errors when I try to stage my application using `sbt clean compile stage`:

```
[error] Not a valid command: stage
[error] Not a valid project ID: stage
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Not a valid key: stage
[error] stage
[error]      ^
```

I have done this hundreds of times on other machines without a problem. I have SBT 0.13.5 -- has anyone seen this before? I have read [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19887917/sbt-stage-not-a-valid-command), but I'm not on Heroku. Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After [the comments above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26535343/why-does-sbt-stage-report-not-a-valid-command/26536033?noredirect=1#comment41705042_26536033) I realized that you just wanted to have `stage` command without bringing the entire Play *foo* in.

The `stage` command is part of [sbt-native-packager](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager) that:

> The goal [of the plugin] is to be able to bundle up Scala software built with SBT for native packaging systems, like deb, rpm, homebrew, msi.

One of the features of the sbt-native-packager plugin is [the stage command](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/packager/universal/UniversalPlugin.scala#L62) that

```
> help stage
Create a local directory with all the files laid out as they would be in the final distribution.
```

Just add the following to `project/plugins.sbt` to have the plugin available in the project (after [the comment of Muki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26535343/why-does-sbt-stage-fail-with-not-a-valid-command/26542862#comment41782726_26542862) the example uses [the latest version 1.0.0-M1](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/releases/tag/v1.0.0-M1) with the autoplugin feature):

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.0.0-M1")
```

You will also have to add the following to `build.sbt`:

```
enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)
```

And that's it! You're all set now.

Execute `stage`.

```
> stage
[info] Packaging /Users/jacek/dev/sandbox/command-build-scala/target/scala-2.10/command-build-scala_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/dev/sandbox/command-build-scala/}command-build-scala...
[info] Wrote /Users/jacek/dev/sandbox/command-build-scala/target/scala-2.10/command-build-scala_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Packaging /Users/jacek/dev/sandbox/command-build-scala/target/scala-2.10/command-build-scala_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Packaging /Users/jacek/dev/sandbox/command-build-scala/target/scala-2.10/command-build-scala_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Nov 5, 2014 2:55:55 PM
```

Comment: Or take a walk on the wild side using sbt 0.13.5 and sbt-native-packager 1.0.0-M1 and just:
`enablePlugins(JavaServerAppPackaging)`

Comment: Whoohoo! I'd say "At long last"! Isn't `enablePlugins` alone part of 0.13.6?

Comment: AFAIK this is already part of 0.13.5. However this shouldn't matter because 0.13.5 and 0.13.6 should be compatible

Comment: This looks promising, but I don't believe it is equivalent to the sbt stage plugin that ships with the Play framework, which produces not a OS package, but an uberjar with all dependencies included, which is what I really need.

Comment: In fact I just added the code below to plugins.sbt and 'sbt stage' works like a charm, generating an uberjar in the target directory:  `resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"  The issue now is I have Play's listener trying to grab port 9000, and I already have a service there -- I can configure it for a different port, but I just don't need a listener in this app.

// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.5")`

Comment: You can do the same with sbt-native-packager and sbt-assembly. http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/DetailedTopics/custom.html#sbt-assembly

Comment: Ah, the uberjar thingy - that's what [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) gives you out of the box. Install it and `sbt assembly` gives you the uberjar. That's however not what you've been asking for in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of digging, I found out 'stage' is implemented by a plugin from the [Play framework](http://playframework.com), which I do use in my other projects and explains why sbt was accepting the stage command.

Comment: Does this mean that you didn't set up the project properly, i.e. `project/plugins.sbt` without `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.5")`?

Comment: Correct. I just don't want to bring the whole Play framework into this other application, which is a backend service without a HTTP interface.

Comment: Fear not. The plugin changes sbt itself with additional tasks and settings and unless you don't use it in your app explicitly, they don't show up anywhere.